# Guzzle api call not working on droplet but working locally

Tags: php, laravel, droplet

Hi I'm trying to get a token from an api but no matter what I try on the droplet I get an invalid client every single time, the code is the same locally and on the droplet, currently working on local but not on the droplet.

This is the code

```
return Cache::rememberForever('payment_token', function () {
    $client = new Client(['http_errors' => false]);

    $params = [
        'client_id' => env('CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
    ];

    $headers = [
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
    ];

    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://apipay.io/auth/token/', [
        'json' => $params,
        'headers' => $headers
    ]);

    $res_body = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents());

    return $res_body->access_token;
});
```

The url for the post isn't a real one, I don't really think it's wise to post the real one as it doesn't work without the client_id and client_secret which I can't post here.

Is there a reason why the droplet would interfere with this? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have it like that if you look, the error doesn't change it says `invalid_client` every time, the URL is `https://api.payments.4geeks.io/authentication/token/` that won't help since you need the client_id and client_secret

Comment: @MartinZeitler well I'm using the same test `client_id` and `client_secret` I thought it would work without issues, I didn't read anything in the docs about having to register the host-name. The docs are in Spanish so I'm not sure you want to take a look https://support-payments.4geeks.io/es/latest/iniciar.html#activacion-de-produccion

Comment: These are the actual API docs: http://docs.payments.4geeks.io/#authentication and they probably might be able to help you there: https://community.4geeks.io/c/4geeks-payments

Comment: maybe the curl/tls version is different on the droplet. I would try with curl from the terminal and see if it works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double-check the remote `.env` file and make sure, that it's not some outdated, cached version of it (which `env()` would then return). Laravel has this feature, which can indeed be quite tricky, while not considering that (eg. it just doesn't work for no apparent reason). `php artisan cache:clear` clears the config-cache and `php artisan config:cache` builds it up again; I even think that production uses a cached config by default (which may be the actual difference there).

Comment: Yea I had to check a couple times, the `client_id` and `client_secret` in my editor the capital O and the 0 look almost exactly the same, I'm sure I had the two mixed up somewhere I rewrote it again and now it's working.

Comment: Access credentials are one of the cases where copy & paste is perfectly fine, if not to be preferred.